# Waiting for insertAdjacentHTML function to complete creation

Tags: javascript, html, insertadjacenthtml

I am creating a paragraph dynamically adding it and then assigning an id to it. While the paragraph gets created, the id does not. I have kept an alert which returns undefined. This is possibly because the code for creating the id gets executed before the paragraph. is created. Is there a way to wait for the element to be created and then assign the id. Some. event listener, or action completions listener. Here is the code that I have taken and modified to explain what I am trying to do:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var h = document.getElementById("myH2");
  var test = "<p>My new paragraph</p>";
  h.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", test);
  test.id = "1234";
  alert(test.id);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Insert a specified text as HTML, in the document.</p>

<h2 id="myH2">My Header</h2>

<p>Click the button to insert a paragraph after the header:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Insert a paragraph</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Test is not a dom element it is a string.

Comment: Oh yes. I understand. Any suggestion how this. can be modified?

Comment: The following should generate a proper paragraph tag:
var test = document.createElement('p');
var textNode = document.createTextNode("My new paragraph.");
test.appendChild(textNode)